# Redirect to a page but get json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a login form as following:

```
<form action="urlLink/auth/signin" method="POST" class="signin form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- the email is expected as the username -->
            <label for="username">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="text-center form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Login</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

After login with "urlLink/auth/signin", it should be redirected to another page ("urlLink"), however I only get a json object after correct login.

for sign in code i use node.js and passport.js. My sign in code is as follows:

```
exports.signin = function(req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate(['ldapauth', 'local'], function(err, user, info) {
    console.log("user in auth is " + JSON.stringify(user.username));
    if (err || !user) {
        res.status(400).send(info);
    } else {
        req.login(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).send(err);
            } else {
                // update user if in status created and a login has happend
                if (user.status === "created") {
                    // use an update because of the pre-code run on each user.save
                    user.status = "registered";
                    user.updated = Date.now();
                    User.update({_id:user._id}, {$set: {status: user.status, updated:user.updated}}, function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(400).send({
                                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                            });
                        } else {
                            // Remove sensitive data before login
                            user.password = undefined;
                            user.salt = undefined;
                            res.json(user);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // Remove sensitive data before login
                    user.password = undefined;
                    user.salt = undefined;
                    res.json(user);
                }
            }
        });
    }
})(req, res, next);
};
```

How can I be redirected properly to the target page? Using JQuery, Ajax, ....? Please help!

Comment: how are you sending the form? please share all the relevant code.

Comment: it looks like you may need to add a redirect in urlLink/auth/signin after the sign in part is done.  can we see the "signin" code ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this (assuming jQuery is included):

```
<script>
  $('#submitbtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = { username:$('#username').val(), password:$('#password').val() };
    $.post(
      $('form.signin').attr('action'),
      data,
      function(res){
        //check your console (F12) to see what is returned from the page - take this out for production
        console.log(res);

        //based on the status you can redirect
        if(res.status == 'registered'){
          window.location = 'urlLink';

          //if you are given a unique id for the user from the server
          //you can append it to the URL too, if necessary - usually
          //something like this is needed, or else someone could look at your
          //JS, and say oh, well I'll just change the filename to urlLink
          //window.location = 'urlLink?userid=' + res._id;
        }
        else{
          alert("Account not registered.");
          //window.location = 'noAuth';
        }
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however I get an error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at urlLink/auth/signin. I am looking to solve this error now.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize the signin page wasn't on the same domain - that's where that issue comes into play. If the API you're signing into supports JSONP, that's probably your easiest way around it... http://json-p.org/

Comment: I added dataType: "jsonp", to post and it solved the CORS problem, but still no success in redirecting to the page and I still get the json object.

Comment: Well, yea, you will get the JSON object, that's kind of the point of doing it via AJAX, get the JSON object, parse it for pertinent information (like login success / user ID), then forward them accordingly. If you use window.location in the success function, they will go to whatever page you use there. If you set it to `window.location='http://google.com'`, let's say, it will forward them to Google, not a JSON object. What is on the page you are forwarding them to (presumably urlLink)?

Comment: The target page contains some forms which then will be filled by json objects which is stored in a mongodb database. The json object which i redirected to it is the json object for the authenticated user.

Comment: You lost me. You use AJAX to send info to and get info from the login page. That object (in my answer it will be named `res` in the success function) contains information about the sign-in. You can parse the object to see if the sign-in was successful. If you open your log [F12] you will see the JSON object. This information is not printed on the screen anywhere - it's only for your JS code to use. If the sign-in succeeded, you transfer them onto the next page (see window.location) - which I believe was your original request.

Comment: If the page you're redirecting the client (not just the JSON object) to is printing out JSON, then I would need to see THAT code to determine why and how to stop it. Likely, though, if it prints out JSON code and you didn't write it, it was probably built to accept AJAX requests and give out JSON objects accordingly (which you would then parse for more useful information), not for redirecting clients to.

Comment: let me to explain: I want to call webpage 'target' but based on the authentication of user from page 'source'. Then the target page should load the corresponding page to the authenticated user. However in current case, it only prints the json object of the user and not show the the target page which should be included some fields related to this user.

Comment: If you forward them (using window.location) successfully to the 'target' page, and it prints out JSON - then something is wrong. Either the 'target' page was setup for AJAX (so you don't forward a user there using window.location, but use AJAX via `$.post` to get information from there), or it wasn't written properly. In either case, I would need to see THAT code to assist.

Comment: thanks for your help: Two things: I get json object printed using the form which I put in the question and without using window.location. Which part of the code you want? it is a  project with many codes. here again i put sign in function: `$scope.signin = function() {
                        $http.post('/auth/signin', $scope.credentials).success($
                                $scope.authentication.user = response;
                                $location.path('/');
                        }).error(function(response) {
                                $scope.error = response.message;`